# Are golang net.UDPConn and net.TCPConn thread safe?? Can i read or write of single UDPConn object in multi thread?

Tags: sockets, go, thread-safety

1.Can we call send from one thread and recv from another on the same net.UDPConn or net.TCPConn objects?

2.Can we call multiple sends parallely from different threads on the same net.UDPConn or net.TCPConn objects?

I am unable to find a good documentation also for the same.
Is golang socket api thread safe?

I find that it is hard to test if it is thread safe.
Any pointers in the direction will be helpful.

My test code is below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "sync"
)

func udp_server() {
    // create listen
    conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &net.UDPAddr{
        IP:   net.IPv4(0, 0, 0, 0),
        Port: 8080,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("listen fail", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 10; i = i + 1 {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(socket *net.UDPConn) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for {
                // read data
                data := make([]byte, 4096)
                read, remoteAddr, err := socket.ReadFromUDP(data)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("read data fail!", err)
                    continue
                }
                fmt.Println(read, remoteAddr)
                fmt.Printf("%s\n\n", data)

                // send data
                senddata := []byte("hello client!")
                _, err = socket.WriteToUDP(senddata, remoteAddr)
                if err != nil {
                    return
                    fmt.Println("send data fail!", err)
                }
            }
        }(conn)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    udp_server()
}
```

Is it OK for this test code?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The documentation for [`net.Conn`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) says:

> Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

> Multiple goroutines may invoke methods on a Conn simultaneously.

My interpretation of the doc above, is that nothing catastrophic will happen if you invoke `Read` and `Write` on a `net.Conn` from multiple go routines, and that calls to `Write` on a `net.Conn` from multiple go routines will be serialised so that the bytes from 2 separate calls to `Write` will not be interleaved as they are written to the network.

The problem with the code you have presented is that there is no guarantee that `Write` will write the whole byte slice provided to it in one go. You are ignoring the indication of how many bytes have been written.

```
_, err = socket.WriteToUDP(senddata, remoteAddr)
```

So to make sure you write everything you would need to loop and call `Write` till all the `senddata` is sent. But `net.Conn` only ensures that data from a *single* call to Write is not interleaved. Given that you could be sending a single block of data with multiple calls to write there is no guarantee that the single block of data would reach its destination intact.

So for example 3 "hello client!" messages could arrive in the following form.

"hellohellohello client! client! client!"

So if you want reliable message writing on a `net.Conn` from multiple go routines you will need to synchronise those routines to ensure that single messages are written intact.

If I wanted to do this, as a first attempt I would have a single go routine reading from one or many message channels and writing to a `net.Conn` and then multiple go routines can write to those message channels.